# Writing files to a hidden location in WPF

Tags: wpf, file

I have to write files to a hidden location in WPF.
I do not want the user to be able to locate these files.

When I'm done writing I plan to upload these files to a separate location.

What is the best location to write to for this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like keylogger specification... why don't you want the user to locate these files? How about encrypting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

More experienced users will always be able to locate files you modify, using tools like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

If you don't want users to see the contents of the files, then encrypt them.

The best location to store application-specific data is `%AppData%\YourApp\` (this is a per-user folder). You'll have write privileges to this folder even if the user isn't administrator.

If you try to save files to location where they need administrator privileges, you'll get User Account Control Dialog Box, and they will recognize that your application tries to access unauthorized location.